# How do I uninstall node using nvm or how uninstall one version of nodejs?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have two versions of node.js installed (10.16.3 and 12.14.1) I use nvm to switch between both. Please how do I uninstall version 10 successfully without affecting version 12?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`nvm uninstall 10.16.3` should do it. See https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#usage-1 for more information.